# How to disable the enter key

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a clicker game in Visual Studio with C#.NET and Windows Forms App. When you click the main button that adds money, you can click enter to automatically click it again. The problem is that you can keep holding down the enter key to repeatadly click the button.

Comment: c# can mean so many technologies.. what technology are you using to build the game?

Comment: And what code you have tried? please provide snipped code.

Comment: I'm not familiar with making GUI apps in C# but I assume there's some sort of `blur()` function that would remove the focus from the button.

Comment: WPF? ASP.NET WebForms? ASP.NET MVC 5? ASP.NET Core MVC? Please **[edit]** the question and clarify.

Comment: [Assuming](https://www.azquotes.com/picture-quotes/quote-you-should-never-assume-you-know-what-happens-when-you-assume-you-make-an-ass-out-of-ellen-degeneres-61-91-22.jpg) you're using WinForms, just add `this.Focus()` to the end of the click event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the event that adds money from "this.keyDown" to "this.KeyUp".
this makes the event only fire after the button is released (after first being pressed). This makes holding down the 'enter' button ineffective, as you would have to release it before something happens.

This still allows the player to just mash the 'enter' key instead of clicking rapidly, but it might be worth considering, as this method doesn't outright disable the 'enter' key

Comment: Where do I wind that event?

Comment: in the properties of the winform button, there is an entire list of events you can choose from, one of them is "KeyDown", another is "KeyUp".
These offer the option to choose which method in the Code Behind to run when the event occurs (if any)

Answer (score 2):

[Assuming](https://www.azquotes.com/picture-quotes/quote-you-should-never-assume-you-know-what-happens-when-you-assume-you-make-an-ass-out-of-ellen-degeneres-61-91-22.jpg) you're using WinForms as your GUI Framework, just add this one line of code:

```
this.Focus();
```

to the end of the button click event handler.

Now, what does it do? Well, when you click on anything in WinForms that element gets the focus, if a Button has the focus pressing enter means activating it. By doing `this.Focus();` we're resetting the focus to the Form instead of the Button

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where are you catching the event, inside a button or, you have to "intercept" the key you are looking for

```
    if (e.KeyChar== 13 )
{
// Do something else or nothing
}
```

[See: Ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

13 = Carriage return

Comment: This is certainly a way to do it, although you don't "have to", I also believe it to not be as clean as my solution, but in some aspects better. Manually playing around with the focus can be a pain in the behind to track down if something isn't behaving as intended

Comment: Of course, you don't have to, there are several solutions to the same problem. I'm just trying to help